# how to limit the size of image that gets submitted with a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm using ckeditor to let users to post image but the thing is, the size of an image that user post can be too big. so I was wondering if I can use some css or javascript to hide the content(would be better to minimize the content but I don't have a clue how I can do that) if the content is too big that it goes out of the box. 
I'm using bootstrap panel as a box

```
<div class="panel-body">

{{ post.content|safe }}

    </div>
```

this post.content can't be too big that it goes out of panel-body, how should I prevent from it going out(hide the content)?

Comment: You can use a css rule on your `.panel-body` like so : `.panel-body { overflow:hidden; }`. Does this solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css `.panel-body { overflow:hidden; }` on your container to hide the overflowing content (your image).

A more elegant solution can be to automatically resize your images to not overflow the container width. You can achieve this with

```
.panel-body img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you .panel-body { overflow:hidden; } did the job, I don't have img field because I'm using wyswyg editor

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment but `.panel-body img` doesn't select elements with class `img`, it really selects all `img` tags inside your `.panel-body`. Did you try it ?

Comment: ckeditor treats image like a content so I can't really play with the image, but with overflow:hidden I can just hide if it gets too big which is enough for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a max-width on your images, like this :

```
.panel-body img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```